# Using Merge GeoProcess task in ArcGIS Engine with C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine, geoprocessing

Having the hardest time getting the correct syntax when adding layers as gp parameters to call the Merge_management GeoProcessing Task.  Below is just one of MANY, MANY ways I have tried with no luck.  Can anyone help?

I've successfully called many GeoProcessing tasks via code in ArcEngine, but this is the first one to take an array ( ie. [layer1,layer2,etc]) as one of the parameters.

Intial Attemp:

```
    public void RunMergeGeoProcess(ILayer SourceLayer1, ILayer SourceLayer2, string ResultFeatureClassName, string GeoDBAbsFileName)
    {

        IFeatureLayer featureLayerSource1 = (IFeatureLayer)SourceLayer1;
        IFeatureLayer featureLayerSource2 = (IFeatureLayer)SourceLayer2;


        _geoProcessor.SetEnvironmentValue("Workspace", GeoDBAbsFileName);
        //_gpParams.Add(featureLayerSource1);
        ////_gpParams.Add(featureLayerSource2);

        IWorkspace refWS = ((IDataset)featureLayerSource1.FeatureClass).Workspace;
        string dbPath = refWS.PathName;

        IDataset myDS1 = featureLayerSource1.FeatureClass as IDataset;
        string mysDS1 = dbPath + "\\" + myDS1.Name;
        IDataset myDS2 = featureLayerSource2.FeatureClass as IDataset;
        string mysDS2 = dbPath + "\\"+ myDS2.Name;

        string myResult = dbPath + "\\" + ResultFeatureClassName;

        string param1 = "[" + mysDS1 + ", " + mysDS2 + "]";

        _gpParams.Add(param1);
        _gpParams.Add(myResult);


        try
        {
            _geoProcessor.OverwriteOutput = true;
            _geoProcessor.Execute("Merge_management", _gpParams, null);
            //returnMessages(_geoProcessor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a GeoProcessing Error." + ex.ToString());
            returnMessages(_geoProcessor);
        }

        _gpParams.RemoveAll();

    }
```

Working Version:

```
    public void RunMergeGeoProcess(ILayer SourceLayer1, ILayer SourceLayer2, string ResultFeatureClassName, string GeoDBAbsFileName)
    {

        IFeatureLayer featureLayerSource1 = (IFeatureLayer)SourceLayer1;
        IFeatureLayer featureLayerSource2 = (IFeatureLayer)SourceLayer2;

        _geoProcessor.SetEnvironmentValue("Workspace", GeoDBAbsFileName);

        IWorkspace refWS = ((IDataset)featureLayerSource1.FeatureClass).Workspace;
        string dbPath = refWS.PathName;

        IDataset myDS1 = featureLayerSource1.FeatureClass as IDataset;
        string mysDS1 = dbPath + "\\" + myDS1.Name;
        IDataset myDS2 = featureLayerSource2.FeatureClass as IDataset;
        string mysDS2 = dbPath + "\\" + myDS2.Name;

        string myResult = dbPath + "\\" + ResultFeatureClassName;
        string param1 =  mysDS2 + ";" + mysDS1  ;
        _gpParams.Add(param1);
        _gpParams.Add(myResult);

        try
        {
            _geoProcessor.OverwriteOutput = true;
            _geoProcessor.Execute("Merge_management", _gpParams, null);
            //returnMessages(_geoProcessor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a GeoProcessing Error during the Merge Operation." + ex.ToString());
            //returnMessages(_geoProcessor);
        }

        _gpParams.RemoveAll();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a semicolon-delimited list for the input parameter. An example using the Intersect tool is below:

```
    private void Intersect(List<string> LayerNames, string OutputLayerLocation)
    {
        Intersect inter;
        StringBuilder sb;
        Geoprocessor gg;

        sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string LayerName in LayerNames)
        {
            sb.Append(LayerName);
            sb.Append(";");
        }

        sb.Length--;

        inter = new Intersect();
        inter.in_features = sb.ToString();
        inter.out_feature_class = OutputLayerLocation;

        gg = new Geoprocessor();
        gg.OverwriteOutput = true;
        gg.ProgressChanged += new EventHandler<ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.ProgressChangedEventArgs>(gg_ProgressChanged);
        gg.ToolExecuted += new EventHandler<ToolExecutedEventArgs>(gg_ToolExecuted);
        gg.MessagesCreated += new EventHandler<MessagesCreatedEventArgs>(gg_MessagesCreated);

        gg.ExecuteAsync(inter);
    }
```

Comment: To put it simply, the tool does not want an array, but a list of paths split on semi-colons: `"C:\\PathToShape1;C:\\PathToShape2;C:\\PathToShape3"`

Comment: @Nathanus That's the odd part; all the documentation I've seen mentions an "array", so I struggled with this myself. (And thanks for making my message a bit clearer.)

Comment: Thanks a TON!!!!!  I could not find that syntax ANYWHERE.  Now it is working, I just need to work on the field mappings (when they are unequal).  Thanks SO much!!!  I'll post my version of final code, when done

Comment: I came from Arcpy scripting, so I simply assumed it wanted the same kind of input it used in Python. Blind luck that I was right. How I came to the conclusion that I should have used a semicolon string instead of the list it shows in the documentation I do not remember... :)

Comment: @user3013 Don't forget to mark Michael's answer as correct (there should be a check mark under the vote count on the side). Glad to be of help.

Comment: Added working code to initial post