# ArcObjects c# .Net Merge with Geoprocessing?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, merge, .net

I'm trying to run the Merge tool using ArcObjects c# .Net. I'm fairly new to the skill but I have been able to run other tools such as Buffer and Points to Line.
However, I have met my match with Merge because it requires more than one input (two layers). Would anyone have an idea how I'm suppose to put two layers into "MergeTool.inputs"? I think right now, my Layer1 is being replaced by Layer2 so when the tool runs, I end up with just one layer being merged into nothing and I get the same layer returned.

```
IMxDocument pMxDoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IMap map = pMxDoc.FocusMap;

        Geoprocessor GPMerge2 = new Geoprocessor();

        ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Merge MergeTool = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.Merge();

        MergeTool.inputs = Layer1;
        MergeTool.inputs = Layer2;
        MergeTool.output = OutputName;

        GPMerge2.Execute(MergeTool, null);
```

Edit: I've seen some solutions to use semicolon and quotes. Something like
MergeTool.inputs = "Layer1;Layer2"
But I'm actually using some variables and I can't get the exact path to the layers to make it into a string. The difference can be seen below if I try to do that. I also want to try and keep this set of code if possible and not set up parameter array.

[image]

Comment: How and where are you setting the Layer1 and Layer2 parameters?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you writing for? Your reference seems to be quite old... have a look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000009wm000000 about executing a tool with IGeoProcessor2 interface with arguments as IVariantArray.

Comment: Usually when you have several inputs, they are separated by commas. If I've ever had a question on what the parameters of a tool are, I would run in manually in the toolbox and examine the results. I use your method of adding parameters instead of using IVariantArray in the geoproccessing tools I write

Comment: Here is more information on the inputs. I made global variables that are set up earlier in the code. MergeTool.inputs = GlobalVariables.Layer1 and MergeTool.inputs = GlobalVariables.Layer2. I tried doing something like MergeTool.inputs = GlobalVariables.Layer1, GlobalVariables.Layer2 but that didn't work. As far as my Arc Version, I'm working in 10.3.1 but I'm new to developing add-ins so I'm probably not utilizing the most up-to-date method. I just use whatever reources I come across in google searches.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17930/need-help-with-merge-geoprocess-task-in-arcengine-c

Comment: According to the most recent version of the .net documentation that has a reference to the Merge object http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_api_ref/GP/topic4789.html the inputs is an *object*, try an array of IFeatureClass objects.. there is no example that I can find to expand on what the *object* is. Note in the example you're still overwriting the inputs parameter with a string. Another method you could try is to write a little python script and then shell it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c

Answer (score 1):

[@mkennedy suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249952/arcobjects-c-net-merge-with-geoprocessing#comment393239_249952) of [Using Merge GeoProcess task in ArcGIS Engine with C#?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17930) wasn't the same example but I was able to get a hint from it.

This wasn't working for my input:

```
MergeTool.inputs = "Layer1;Layer2"
```

But this worked:

```
MergeTool.inputs = Layer1 + ";" + Layer2
```